# kotlin - non null mark for platform types / methods

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-interop

I often use `UUID.randomUUID()`. Type inferred by kotlin is `UUID!`. is there any way to tell kotlin that return type of this specific method is `UUID` and is always non null? or do i have to do everywhere `UUID.randomUUID()!!` or implement my own method?

Comment: Do you control the source of the method producing UUIDs?

Comment: UUID is part of java sdk, so no

Comment: Oh, I misread. I thought you had a method that emitted UUIDs (generated with UUID.randomUUID()). Gotcha.

Comment: huh? if it's a platform type (`!`) it's up to you whether you want to treat it as nullable or not. You don't need to use `!!`. Just don't declare the variable with `?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you explicitly declare the types, it should declare them non-nullable instead of as a platform type.

```
val id1 = UUID.randomUUID() // UUID!
val id2: UUID = UUID.randomUUID()  // UUID
```

I do this with a function to make things a bit easier. By declaring the return type, it has the same effect:

```
fun generateUUID(): UUID = UUID.randomUUID()
```

Or as an extension:

```
fun UUID.next(): UUID = UUID.randomUUID()
```

Comment: This is unsafe casting, right? Have to be careful if `UUID.randomUUID()` returns null, then id2 could be null and skip the compile time check.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin does not force you to use `!!` on platform types. If the return value of the function from Java does not have nullability annotations `@NotNull` or `@Nullable`, it can be treated as either nullable or non-null:

```
val uuid1: UUID = UUID.randomUUID()
val uuid2: UUID? = UUID.randomUUID()
```

If you treat it as an non-null type but it is actually null, exception will be thrown.

> [Kotlin's doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types):
>   If we choose a non-null type, the compiler will emit an assertion upon assignment. This prevents Kotlin's non-null variables from holding nulls. Assertions are also emitted when we pass platform values to Kotlin functions expecting non-null values etc. Overall, the compiler does its best to prevent nulls from propagating far through the program (although sometimes this is impossible to eliminate entirely, because of generics).